# Load partial based on route parameter in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to load a partial based on a parameter that is coming through a route?  I've created a landing page template, and I'd like to tweak the main messaging a little bit based on industry.  To complicate matters, the parameter needs to be optional.

For instance, if the URL is

- `www.domain.com/medical` I want to render the partial `landing/medical` within `layouts/header.html.erb` which is rendered in `layouts/application.html.erb`
- `www.domain.com/legal` I want to render the partial `landing/legal` within `layouts/header.html.erb` which is rendered in `layouts/application.html.erb`
- `www.domain.com` renders the default partial `landing/default.html.erb`

Here's an example of my current views:

**landing/medical.html.erb**

```
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Are you HIPAA Compliant?</h1>
  Find out more by signing up below...
</div>
```

**landing/legal.html.erb**

```
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Your Legal Practice needs help</h1>
  <p class="leadFind out why by by signing up below...
</div>
```

**landing/default.html.erb**

```
<div class="heading">
  <h1>What are you doing?</h1>
  Probably nothing...
</div>
```

**layouts/header.html.erb**

```
<div class="heading">
  <%= render 'the/optional/partial' %>
</div>
```

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  <% if content_for?(:head) %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
    <% end %>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <%= render 'layouts/header' unless @disable_heading %>

            <div class="cover-container">

                <div class="inner cover">
                    <%= yield %>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>

    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some info is missing and it probably can lead to different ways to do it.

You can specify the parameter in the route:

**routes.rb**

`get '/(:industry_param)' => 'welcome#index'`

With this, assuming your website root is going to that route you will have now access to a variable `params[:industry_param]` that you can use to conditionally render the corresponding template:

**welcome_controller.rb**

`@industry = params[:industry_param] || 'default'`

**layouts/header.html.erb**

```
<div class="heading">
  <%= render "landing/#{@industry}" %>
</div>
```

I think you can start from this. Have some security considerations like filtering the parameter in the controller and only accepting certain values, etc.

Comment: what would your suggestion be in the controller if there is no `params[:industry_param]` passed in the url?

Comment: You should be able to add `, industry_param: 'default'` to your route.

Comment: Hmmm @Puce, `get "/(:industry)/(:referrer_url)", to: "users#new", defaults: { industry: 'default' }` results in `The partial name (landing/) is not a valid Ruby identifier` in `ArgumentError in Users#new` now.

Comment: in the controller, ended up doing this: @industry = params[:industry]  || "default"

Comment: @Godzilla74 I updated my answer with your code. I just provided a quick untested answer to point you in the right direction :)